# Powershell Form autorun every minute

Tags: forms, powershell

I can create a Powershell form with buttons etc that do stuff including reading a database upon a user click eg

```
$button1.add_click({
$label1.Text = "Checking"
$url_handle = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url_to_poll)
#more stuff here
})
```

What I wish to create is a form that is loaded and starts polling the database automatically (eg without a user clicking a button) and repeat every minute.  There will be buttons on the form that do other stuff but it's the bit above I cannot seem to work out?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a timer and use the tick event. See:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you.  I have looked at timers but all the sample code I have seen require the user to click a button to start - is there a way of of having it start automatically?

Comment: Thanks, I seem to cobbling enough code together to do what I need.

Comment: Hi, you can use the form.Onload method to start the timer.